# "Cannot Execute Boolean Operation" on a subdivided mesh

Tags: modifiers

So, I'm sure alot of people have asked this but I'm not sure if any answer applies to this problem, so I'm just going to go ahead and ask.
I editied a cube and subdivided it, then imported an SVG image and made it into a mesh, now i want to subtract the SVG image from the cube, when i went to apply the boolean it doesn't work. Here's the screenshot, I'm also uploading the .blend file. Any help would be great thank you.[image]

Here's the link for the download of the .blend file, I wasn't sure what was the best way to upload it so I used MediaFire, hope that doesn't raise any issues.

http://www.mediafire.com/file/iyondoyj4swq3jv/BlendProblem.blend/file

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=cannot%20execute%20boolean%20operation

Answer (score 1):

After some tries I've found a way to do it:

- Select your curve, go in Edit mode, select all and <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles*. You must have duplicated some vertices somehow, that's what causes your problem. Now you could apply your *Boolean* but still, you won't get a good result, so wait a bit.
- To simplify your topology you can also do a <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve*.
- Now, select your shield and apply the *Subsurf* and the *Solidify* modifier.
- Then apply the *Boolean* modifier, it will give a correct result.